# Premixed Gatorade and Powerade aren't cheap. I'd rather buy something powdered or concentrated. What's kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, health-safety-shmira, choleh-sick, product-recommendation

I'm sick today; I think it might be (mild) gastroenteritis. [DuPont et al.](http://gi.org/guideline/acute-infectious-diarrhea-in-adults/) write that "the most important form of therapy consists of fluid combined with electrolytes", citing [the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/00018677.htm).

I'd rather use a commercial electrolyte product, but Pedialyte isn't cheap, and I don't want to pay $1 per bottle for premixed Gatorade or Powerade either.

What can I buy that's kosher and cheaper?

Comment: I know you want a premixed, but making it yourself is fairly easy: 1 c OJ, 1 c water, 1 tbsp salt (or maybe tsp, I forget)

Comment: Dear readers: The question still has no upvotes. As for you, personally, why did you not vote the question up? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked online for information, and I checked my local supermarket. I didn't phone any companies.

- Pedialyte has a hechsher. But even if you buy the powder, you'll still pay $4-$5 to make one liter.

Okay, fine, maybe I'll buy a sports drink concentrate instead. These products also claim to help replenish lost electrolytes. I looked mostly for information about Gatorade and Powerade products, though I stumbled across some information about Clif Shot too.

- Gatorade mix (powder) has no hechsher. Gatorade [does](http://www.oukosher.org/) make concentrate with a hechsher, but you can only buy it in huge four-liter jugs.
- Powerade makes both mixes (powders) and sugar-free concentrated "drops" with OU certification. Searching OU's website will yield no information; maybe Coca-Cola has requested the OU to hide the information from the website. Do a search at walmart.com then click the "kosher" checkbox on the left side to filter your search results.
- Or you can buy Mio Sport concentrated sugar-free "drops" with OK certification.
- Clif Shot makes KSA-certified mixes (powders). The Houston Kashruth Association [writes](http://kosherhouston.org/category/hka-bulletin/recent-bulletins/), "The national kosher organizations have informed us that KSA certified products are now acceptable but only if product is from USA/Canada." I don't know where Clif Shot mix is made.

I didn't look for information about electrolyte products in tablet form.

In the end, visit your local full-service supermarket and see what they have.

This post is community wiki. Please edit it and add to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've done homebrew in the past: raw (unsweetened) Kool Aid packets mixed to 1/2 sweetness, with a mixture of salts (e.g KCl and NaCl). You can substitute syrups for granulated sugar. Google around for recipes.